# Android Convert string in TextView to Emoji

Tags: android

I'm writing an application that allow users to chat, but I have problems in applying the emjois, now what I have like some user send a message 
`Hello :)`
the other user see the message as it is, I need to convert `:)` to user device emoji.

how can I accomplish this?? is there any good library on Github that replace all the texts to emojis ??

Any help please. I'm stuck on this for hours

Comment: Check this https://github.com/delight-im/Emoji/tree/master/Android

Comment: @Skizo it didn't work.. I this what is needed is java class to convert user inputs like :) to unicode

Answer (score 2):

Emojis are handled by TextView, EditText's by default, it all depends on font your current device having by default.
You can add emojis using unicode's from [here](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

See for example [Grinning face emoji](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm) and it's unicode value for java `"\uD83D\uDE00"`

Comment: I've tested this on different devices, the text view doesn't support emoji by default, but I have other applications installed on my devices that shows emjois, and I can't force user to write Unicode to get emoji

Comment: If you want to use standarized emoji's you have to change i.e. ':)' string value to unicode emoji. And like i said TextView is supporting it, on some older devices where is no Roboto font there could be some problems. But i.e. WhatsApp app, Samsung SMS application are using standard emojis and it's working. 
People are even sending emojis in standard notification messages and android is rendering those emojis correctly.

Comment: And if you still don't think this is possible, check libraries from https://android-arsenal.com/tag/33 those are open source so you will easily check how magically they are adding emojis :)

Comment: it didn't work, I guess what I need is a class to convert user input like :) to proper Unicode emoji format